# angular2 ngif not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angularjs-ng-if

I have a div in my HTML and i want to show it when a file is uploading.
its a simple `*ngIf` but somehow its not working :(

HTML

```
<div  
  *ngIf="loading" 
  style="width: 100%;height: 100%;
  position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;background-color: darkgray;opacity: 
  0.7;z-index: 9999">
</div>

<button type="button" (click)="upload('#hqdl','vidhq')">
  upload
</button>
```

TS

```
upload(obj: string,url: string) {
    this.loadning = true;
    let fileCount: number = inputEl.files.length;
    let formData = new FormData();
    if (fileCount > 0) { 
        formData.append('data', inputEl.files.item(0));
        this.http.post(URL+url, formData).map((data : Response)=>data.json()).subscribe(
         data =>{
             if(data.success){
                 alert('OK');
                 this.loadning = false;
                }
             else{
                 alert('ERR');
                 this.loadning = false;
                }
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: spelling mistake ` this.loading= true;` and i think in html is should be '*ngIf="controller.loading"'

Comment: beware of spelling mistakes, you wrote `loadning` instead of `loading`

Comment: OMG it took two hours of my time. bytheway just ‍‍‍‍`*ngif="loading"` is work for me. thanks @Usmanlqbal